# Why update panel is working after 2 clicks

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I making a website that needs a like button on some posts.

I made the like button but and the removing like button and every thing is good.

But when I made the Label that has the number of likes the update panel of the number of like didn't refresh at the first click but in the second click the update panel made what it supposed to make when I clicked the first time.

Please need help.

```html
<td align="left">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
          <ContentTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="Like" runat="server" class="ll glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" OnClick="Like_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="dilike" runat="server" class="ll glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" style="color:cornflowerblue" OnClick="dilike_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
          </ContentTemplate>
          <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Like" EventName="Click" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dilike" EventName="Click" />
          </Triggers>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
<td align="right">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dilike" EventName="Click" />
           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Like" EventName="Click" />
     </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

</td>
```

```
    protected void Like_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["login"]);
        int postid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        string sql = "insert into likes([for],[by]) values(" + postid + "," + id + ")";
        conDB.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
        dilike.Visible = true;
        Like.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void dilike_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["login"]);
        int postid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
        string sql = "delete from likes where for=" + postid + " AND by=" + id + "";
        conDB.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
        dilike.Visible = false;
        Like.Visible = true;
    }

PageLoad{

//check like
            string sqll = "select by from likes where for="+postid+" AND by="+id+"";
            if (conDB.ExecuteScalar(sqll) == null)
            {
                Like.Visible = true;
                dilike.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                dilike.Visible = true;
                Like.Visible = false;
            }

            //count likes
            string sqll2 = "select count(by) from likes where for=" + postid + "";
            Label7.Text = conDB.ExecuteScalar(sqll2).ToString() + " Likes";

}
```